# Embedding a random date generator into an embedded ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to add this random date generator into my erb file...

```
def time_rand from = 0.0, to = Time.now
  Time.at(from + rand * (to.to_f - from.to_f))
end
```

I apologise if this may seem simple but I do not know how to make this show up in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a view Helper (the `application_helper.rb` or `your_controller_helper.rb`, in you `app/helpers` folder)

The first will make the method available to all views. The second only to you controller's views.

Then you can use it in your view:

```
<%= time_rand some_time, some_other_time %>
```